# why does python logging level in basicConfig have no effect?

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging

# root logger
root = logging.getLogger()      # root
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARN)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[root] %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(ch)

# logging as child
c = logging.getLogger('mod')
c.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[mod] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
c.addHandler(ch)

c.error('foo')
c.warning('foo')
c.info('foo')
c.debug('foo')
```

output:

```
[mod] - ERROR - foo
[root] ERROR - foo
[mod] - WARNING - foo
[root] WARNING - foo
[mod] - INFO - foo
[mod] - DEBUG - foo
```

It's OK. Level of root is `WARN`, so `INFO` and `DEBUG` of root is not printed.
But when I use `basicConfig`:

```
import logging

# config root logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN, format='[root] %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# logging as child
c = logging.getLogger('mod')
c.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[mod] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
c.addHandler(ch)

c.error('foo')
c.warning('foo')
c.info('foo')
c.debug('foo')
```

output:

```
[mod] - ERROR - foo
[root] ERROR - foo
[mod] - WARNING - foo
[root] WARNING - foo
[mod] - INFO - foo
[root] INFO - foo
[mod] - DEBUG - foo
[root] DEBUG - foo
```

The level of `basicConfig` is `WARN`, why level `INFO` and `DEBUG` of root can be printed?

And when I use `logging.info`, it effects.

Comment: You have `ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in your second example, if you use `ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in your first example you will see the exact same output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are seeing those `[root]` info and debug messages because your call to `logging.basicConfig` creates a root **Handler** with a level of `NOTSET`. A handler with a level of `NOTSET` will output any message it receives (see [Handler.setLevel](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel)).

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN, format='[root] %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
>>> [handler.level == logging.NOTSET for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers]
[True]
```

This differs from your first example because in your first example you are creating a root handler with a level of `WARN`.

The `level=` parameter for `logging.basicConfig` is used to set the level of the root **Logger** not any root **Handler**.

#### Log message propagation

Log messages are propagated up to parent Loggers but the level of any parent Loggers is not considered. It is the level of any **Handlers** that decides what gets "outputted".

From the docs for [logging.Logger.propagate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate):

> Messages are passed directly to the ancestor loggers’ handlers - neither the level nor filters of the ancestor loggers in question are considered.

#### What is Logger.level for then?

A Logger uses its level to decide if to propagate a message to its and any parent loggers' handlers.

If a Logger does not have a level set then it asks its ancestor Loggers for their level and uses that (see [`logging.Logger.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel)).

So, the root logger's level is only relevant if you have not set the level on your child logger.