# Level set in logging.basicConfig does not have the expected effect

Tags: python, logging

Python's `logging.basicConfig` does not behave as I would expect. In the code below messages sent with `logging.warn` get sent even though I've called `basicConfig` with a level of `ERROR`.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
root = logging.getLogger()
print("root.level", logging.getLevelName(root.level))
print("Levels for root.handlers: {}".format(
        [logging.getLevelName(handler.level) for handler in root.handlers]))
logging.warn("You're seeing this even though you called basicConfig with level=logging.ERROR")
root.warn("You're seeing this too")

root.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.warn("But you won't see this")
```

The output produced is

```
root.level WARNING
Levels for root.handlers: ['NOTSET']
WARNING:root:You're seeing this even though you called basicConfig with level=logging.ERROR
WARNING:root:You're seeing this too
```

Note that the final call to `logging.warn`, once I've called `root.setLevel` myself, does indeed fail to produce output as expected.

What good is the `level` argument for `logging.basicConfig` if it has no effect in this simple setting? And if I want to control what level of messages get output in a simple setting such as this one, is the preferred approach to call `root.setLevel`?

Here's my version info:

```
# sys.version = 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:03:53) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

There are several questions already on stackoverflow that seem to be the same as this one, but all the ones I've found are actually about other things:

1. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943747/python-logging-before-you-run-logging-basicconfig) is trying to run `logging.basicConfig` after he's already done some logging
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848281/python-logging-set-level-in-basicconfig) attempts to call `logging.basicConfig` more than once (producing an effect similar to #1)
3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471999/why-does-python-logging-level-in-basicconfig-have-no-effect) involves using a child logger

Comment: Using the exact code above I have been unable to replicate this with either python 2.7 or 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code as given, I have been unable to replicate your problem.  Instead, the output is as expected.

```
root.level ERROR
Levels for root.handlers: ['NOTSET']
```

Is it possible that you have a `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` that is being invoked by python at startup?  These are often used to provide logging setups.

The function `basicConfig` does nothing at all if the root handlers have already been initialised.  So, if you have such a file doing setup already, then this second `basicConfig` call will be a no-op.

Try running your code using either of the following:

```
python3.4 -I
```

or

```
python2.7 -ES
```

These flags will help isolate your environment and prevent the import of `site` (which then imports `sitecustomize` etc).